# Need CSS to make all fields in-line when shown within a browser

Tags: html, css, forms, field

Hey guys just a simple problem with CSS. I want my form fields to be in-line. I need the CSS to make my fields preview in a browser in-line. For example:

Input type: color...................*Field goes here*

Input type: date....................*Field goes here*

Input type: datetime.............*Field goes here*

Input type: datetime-local.....*Field goes here*  and so on...

Input type: email...................*Field goes here*  and so on...

Input type: month

Any support will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: you forgot to include the code you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried? It would be very helpful (and courteous) that you provide us with a minimal example.

Comment: Unless you do something special, this is what will happen by default.

Comment: I don't know the code, that's the point. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The elitism is getting absurd.  If you've got no help to offer say nothing.  Every post I go to has someone complaining and people giving a thumbs up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a multiple ways you could do it. Here are a couple examples:

**Example One:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="color">Color:</label> 
        <input id="color" type="text" value="color" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input id="date" type="text" value="date" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS: (*very little css needed*)

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
label {
  width:40px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4GkLb/2/

**Example 2:**

*And another way with no CSS(Let the browser do the work)*

```
<div>
    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input id="date" type="text" value="date" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="date">Color:</label> 
    <input id="date" type="text" value="color" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QedEB/

**note:**

To get the fields to align you will need to add a width to the labels (*like example 1*). However this (imo) is a simpler / more semantic way to code the HTML in order to force line breaks after each "label input group". [See With CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/QedEB/1/)

This format is most similar to Bootstrap which I prefer, seems most semantic in most cases. However that depends on content / data. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Your second example doesn't align fields. Moreover, `<label>` should include `<input>`, or you should use `for` attribute otherwise.

Comment: @Oril, Yeah I didn't add a width to the labels in the second example. I wanted to show the OP what it would look like without CSS. I guess I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect those changes. Also to better explain what Oril is talking about. Here is a resource. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label With both examples.